# Is this possible to find employees who have above average salary without using subquery and joins?

Tags: sql

This is my query to find the employees who have a salary that is above the average. I'm using a subquery:

```
SELECT salary 
FROM Employee 
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employee)
```

Is this possible to find those employees without using a subquery and joins?

Comment: We have to find average salary too

Comment: Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You need to somehow obtain the average salary and you need to build a separate query to get this.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Do you consider a derived table `select * from (select .. ) t` a "sub-query"?

Comment: You don't generally optimize SQL by avoiding certain keywords or features. The above query is *clear* and *understandable*. Why are you seeking to change it?

Comment: seeking for more efficient  solution

Comment: There's unlikely to be a solution that can generate the result set you're looking for more efficiently. Calculating the average is going to require examining all salaries in the table. Outputting the above average salaries is almost certainly going to require a second scan of the salary data. It doesn't matter how the query is *structured*, that's the reality of this set of requirements, and a good optimizer will produce a query that involves two scans (of the table or an index), no matter how you write the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a result that only shows the highest salary above the average (as opposed to *all* salaries above average) is acceptable, then this can be done without a sub-select:

```
select salary, 
       salary - avg(salary) over () as diff_to_average,
       avg(salary) over () as average_salary 
from employees
order by 2 desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

(The above is standard ANSI SQL)

The drawback is that you can't remove the  `diff_to_average` column as you can't use the alias in a where clause on the same level (you can remove the `average_salaray` though). The whole question doesn't really make sense though.

One solution that does not use a sub-select, but only a derived table is:

```
select *
from (
  select salary, avg(salary) over () as average_salary
  from employees
) t
where salary > average_salary
order by salary;
```

The derived table is only necessary because SQL does not allow to (re)use a column alias in the WHERE clause on the same level.

However depending on the DBMS, the query in your question might be more efficient as the window function in the derived table typically requires some sort of buffering which would not happen when using the sub-select from your question.

I created a table with three columns: id, name ans salary and a million rows and then compared the two queries. I did not create an index on the salary column.

### Postgres 10 results:

The query using the window function buffers the result in order to evaluate the it:

```
Sort  (cost=50423.64..51256.98 rows=333333 width=73) (actual time=598.267..608.075 rows=500409 loops=1)
  Sort Key: t.salary
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 82659kB
  Buffers: shared hit=9346
  ->  Subquery Scan on t  (cost=0.00..19846.00 rows=333333 width=73) (actual time=218.982..454.620 rows=500409 loops=1)
        Filter: ((t.salary)::numeric > t.average_salary)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 499591
        Buffers: shared hit=9346
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.00..13846.00 rows=1000000 width=73) (actual time=218.978..336.965 rows=1000000 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=9346
              ->  Seq Scan on emp  (cost=0.00..10346.00 rows=1000000 width=41) (actual time=0.022..55.422 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=9346
Planning time: 0.099 ms
Execution time: 671.334 ms
```

The solution from your question using a sub-query is much more efficient as it does not need any intermediate memory:

```
Seq Scan on emp  (cost=12846.00..28192.00 rows=333333 width=41) (actual time=122.729..301.144 rows=500409 loops=1)
  Filter: ((salary)::numeric > $0)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 499591
  Buffers: shared hit=18692
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=12846.00..12846.00 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=122.715..122.715 rows=1 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=9346
          ->  Seq Scan on emp emp_1  (cost=0.00..10346.00 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.004..54.477 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                Buffers: shared hit=9346
Planning time: 0.062 ms
Execution time: 309.586 ms
```

### Oracle 12.1 results

The Oracle execution plans look very similar and Oracle as well buffers the results in case of the window function:

```
SQL_ID  2x0xhkm1pkamz, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select * from (   select salary, avg(salary) over () as average_salary  
 from emp ) t where salary > average_salary order by salary

Plan hash value: 1471144246

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes|E-Temp | Cost (%CPU)| A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |      1 |        |       |       |  6660 (100)|    500K|00:00:01.02 |    6679 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY       |      |      1 |    655K|    16M|    22M|  6660   (1)|    500K|00:00:01.02 |    6679 |    17M|  1562K|   15M (0)|
|*  2 |   VIEW               |      |      1 |    655K|    16M|       |  1812   (1)|    500K|00:00:00.79 |    6679 |       |       |          |
|   3 |    WINDOW BUFFER     |      |      1 |    655K|  8325K|       |  1812   (1)|   1000K|00:00:00.65 |    6679 |    34M|  2096K|   30M (0)|
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |      1 |    655K|  8325K|       |  1812   (1)|   1000K|00:00:00.09 |    6679 |       |       |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$1
   2 - SEL$2 / T@SEL$1
   3 - SEL$2
   4 - SEL$2 / EMP@SEL$2

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("SALARY">"AVERAGE_SALARY")
```

As with Postgres, the query using the sub-select is more efficient in Oracle as well:

```
SQL_ID  6fmzs2ru2cxa5, child number 1
-------------------------------------
select * from emp  where salary > (select avg(salary) from emp)

Plan hash value: 1876299339

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |      1 |        |       |  1814 (100)|    500K|00:00:00.27 |   14347 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL  | EMP  |      1 |    500K|    37M|     2   (0)|    500K|00:00:00.27 |   14347 |
|   2 |   SORT AGGREGATE    |      |      1 |      1 |    13 |            |      1 |00:00:00.18 |    6679 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |      1 |    655K|  8325K|  1812   (1)|   1000K|00:00:00.09 |    6679 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$1 / EMP@SEL$1
   2 - SEL$2
   3 - SEL$2 / EMP@SEL$2

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("SALARY">)
```

---

So if your question is: I am looking for a more efficient query, then the answer is (at least for the two databases above): your query is as efficient as it gets.